# Positioning three divs inside a div, but it overlaps

Tags: css, position, css-float

I'm sorry, I have no other way to describe this and I've frustrated myself to tears trying to figure out how to get it to stop.

I'm trying to make it so that the black div in my image https://i.stack.imgur.com/izEU0.png increases its width WITH the grey div instead of the grey one overlapping. The red one is just a placeholder for an image, ignore that.

The black and grey divs do not have a height attribute, because I don't want to make them into scrolly boxes, I want their height to increase with the amount of text. The white and red ones do, and I swear I have checked fifty times to make SURE there is no height attribute present in either the black OR grey divs. When I increase the height of the red/white divs the black one also gets bigger.

Ok I think I've provided enough detail, is there a way to fix this?? I've googled for hours and I just can't figure this out, I never post questions on places because I always figure it out before I even get an answer but I'm desperate.

Comment: And of course I figured it out right after asking ugh I don't know how to delete this.

Comment: Can you please post some HTML & CSS or post a demo (using something like http://jsfiddle.net/) otherwise it's very difficult to know how to help you

Comment: My instinct would be to use `overflow: hidden` on the black container, but I'm not 100% sure that will work without seeing what your code is like

Comment: Hit delete next to the "share | edit | delete | flag" directly beneath your tags. If this doesn't work, you have to flag it for a moderator to delete. You'll have to describe it to them, I would say something along the lines of, "This question does not belong in this atmosphere of the stack overflow forum." It usually takes about 30 min to a day to get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is needed to give you the exact solution but I hope [`this jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/VbSgk/) will give you a way to understand how this effect can be achieved and what you might be missing.

If you could provide your code then maybe it is possible to provide an exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had cleared floats after your grey div. You can do something like below:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```